# Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in

Tags: php, arrays, scalar

I am seeing the following error when executing my status script:

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in 

$result[$array[$i*2]] = $array[$i*2+1];
```

What am I doing wrong?
I have included the full code below:

```
<?php 

// Set the host and port 
$host = "ip_goes_here"; 
$port = port_goes_here; 

// Open the socket connection to the server 
$fp = fsockopen("udp://".$host, $port); 

// Set the string to send to the server 
$string = "\xff\xff\xff\xffgetinfo"; 

// Set the socket timeout to 2 seconds 
socket_set_timeout($fp, 2); 

// Actually send the string 
fwrite($fp, $string); 

// Read the first 18 bytes to get rid of the header and do the error checking here 
if(!fread($fp, 18)) { 

      die("Oh God, the pain!"); 
} 

// Get the status of the socket, to be used for the length left 
$status = socket_get_status($fp); 

// Read the rest 
$info = fread($fp, $status['unread_bytes']); 

// Explode the result of the fread into another variable 
$array = explode("\\", $info); 

// Loop through and create a result array, with the key being even, the result, odd 
for($i = 0; $i < count($array)/2; $i++) { 

    $result[$array[$i*2]] = $array[$i*2+1];
} 

// Print the result for error checking 
print_r($result);     

// Close the file pointer 
fclose($fp);
```

The line I mentioned is causing the errors. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: Obviously `$array` isn't an array, even if the variable is named so. It may also be that you've already set `$result` as a scalar... Without showing the code, where you set these variables, no one could tell you what's wrong.

Comment: This question is Off-topic: No Repro because we cannot see where `$result` is declared as a scalar value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try declaring the variable `$result`, as an array, before using it.

```
$result = array();
// Loop through and create a result array, with the key being even, the result, odd 
for($i = 0; $i < count($array)/2; $i++) { 

    $result[$array[$i*2]] = $array[$i*2+1];
}
```